# How to link local generated library or imported library automatically in CMake

Tags: c++, cmake

Below is a simple version of our project:

```
project/
├── CMakeLists.txt
├── dependency
│   └── CMakeLists.txt
├── factory_test
│   ├── CMakeLists.txt
│   └── FactoryTest.cpp
├── install
│   ├── include
│   │   └── locator
│   └── lib
│       └── locator
└── locator
    ├── CMakeLists.txt
    ├── Locator.cpp
    └── Locator.h
```

Content of CMakeLists.txt of dependency:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.12)

project(dependency)

function(import_lib lib_name lib_dir_name)
    add_library(${lib_name} STATIC IMPORTED GLOBAL)
    set_target_properties(${lib_name} PROPERTIES
        INTERFACE_INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/install/include
        IMPORTED_LOCATION ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/install/lib/${lib_dir_name}
        IMPORTED_IMPLIB ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/install/lib/${lib_dir_name})
endfunction()

import_lib(import_locator locator/liblocator.a)
```

Content of CMakeLists.txt of factory_test:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.12)

project(factory_test)

add_library(factory_test FactoryTest.cpp)
target_link_library(factory_test PUBLIC import_locator)
```

Content of CMakeLists.txt of locator:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.12)

project(locator)

add_libary(locator Locator.cpp)

install(FILES Locator.h ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/install/include/locator)
install(TARGET locator ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/install/lib/locator)
```

Content of top CMakeLists.txt:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.12)

project(test_project)

add_subdirectory(dependency)
add_subdirectory(locator)
add_subdirectory(factory_test)
```

The dependency hierarchy is factory_test depend on dependency. And we'd like to build the project at top directory. The purpose we write CMake so is that we want all the subdirectories depend on install directory, so that we can build any one of the subdirectories without it's dependent subdirectory.

Our problem with this CMake proposal is that if the interface of locator is modified and we want to build the project in top level directory, it will fail. Because the locator library is still not exported to install directory. Our current method is first build locator and export it to install, and then build all other targets.

So I was wondering if it's possible for CMake that the factory_test can dynamically link to local generated locator library if the locator directory exists or link to imported locator library if the directory doesn't exist or there is a better CMake proposal for this problem?

Hope someone familiar with this can give us some advices. Thanks for advance.

Comment: When you say CMake will fail, what is the *exact* CMake error you get? Also, why not have `factory_test` depend directly on the `locator` target? They should only rebuild `locator` if there are changes to the `locator` project, or the build is cleaned.

Comment: The build will fail is because the interface of locator is changed, but it is not exported to install directory yet when build. And factory_test is dependant on the imported locator, it's still the old locator library, so the build will fail. The reason why we don't directly depend on lcoator target is that, not all of the members have the authority to access all the directories, but they all can access to install directory. If you need more information, please let me know.

Answer (score 1):

You could put an if-statement in your `factory_test/CMakeLists.txt` to check for the existence of the `locator` directory. This would determine whether to link to the `locator` CMake target directly, or the imported locator target.

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.12)

project(factory_test)

add_library(factory_test FactoryTest.cpp)

# Check if the 'locator' directory exists.
if(EXISTS ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/locator)
    target_link_library(factory_test PUBLIC locator)
else()
    target_link_library(factory_test PUBLIC import_locator)
endif()
```

You may have to adjust the check in the if-statement, as it wasn't clear from your description which directories/files are accessible and which are not. Also, I imagine you may want a similar check in the top-level CMake file, as it will traverse to the `locator` directory by default.

Comment: Yes, your are right, we are checking in the top-level CMake file using a directory traversing, here I just put it this way for simplicity. Your are really careful about this. I also figure out that I can do it this way, but I was wondering if there is a more elegant way to do this in modern CMake? If there is no other way to do this, I will try your answer. Thanks.